# How do I use Honey Malt?

Tags: flavor, specialty-malt

I hope this isn't too stupid a question.  (I am a "noob")

I wanted to experiment with some additional flavourings in my latest brew, and was pondering using Honey Malt, such as [this](http://www.thehomebrewcompany.co.uk/honey-malt-crushed-500g-p-3467.html).

But can someone tell me how I am supposed to use it? I see it listed as a "flavouring" on some other sites, yet it is a "malt"? So at what stage, and how, do I add it? Is it supposed to be thrown in right at the beginning, or is it something I only add in late fermentation?

Thanks

Comment: Do you brew all grain or kits?

Comment: Hi, I am using this kit: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Woodfordes-Sundew-3Kg-40pt-beer/dp/B00CBWXJ12 Thanks

Comment: Just FYI never add grains to fermentation unless the intent is natural lactobacillus sour fermentation..

Comment: @EvilZymurgist Thanks... but I have no idea what that means ;) As I say, I'm a noob. Can you explain? And relate to chthon's answer below, who seems to say I should add it right at the beginning, with primary fermentation? You're saying I'll end up with a sour taste.. alongside the honey taste? OK. So how would you suggest I add it then, in order to avoid those kind of side effects?

Comment: @Inigo grains have naturally bacteria that is killed during a boil. Grains are not intended for a fermentation addition, they need a boil after or the bacteria will sour the beer. What you want to do is mash them or steep the grain in your wort. To steep, you place them in a bag in the wort, as the wort is warming up is the steep. Remove them at 168°F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using grains for a kit, you should steep them. That is the simplest. According to [this question](https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/threads/should-i-minimash-honey-malt-or-just-steep-it.332492/) it is normally better to mash honey malt, but you can steep it too.

For steeping put your grains in a bag and add 1,5 l water of 65°C to it. Let it rest for half an hour, then replace part of the water needed for the kit with the amount of extract obtained by the steeping. Your honey malt will absorb some water.

Comment: I also recommend reading a book about brewing. http://www.howtobrew.com/ can be read online, and it also goes into basics of kits and extract brewing. Good luck.

Comment: why 65°C and not (for example) 75°C or 50°C? Depending on whether the wort is boiled or not, IMHO it is quite reasonable to steep non mashed grain at room temp and sometime it is optimal to steep at lower temps.

Comment: @barking.pete: Not too high to avoid tannin extraction, not too low so that life forms are killed, and around the same temperature that is used to heat water to mix with the liquid malt extract. In case of a boiled kit indeed not necessary, but I read too much that boiled kits get that 'homebrew twang'.